$P(x)$ with rational coefficients, but $P(P(x))$ with integer coefficients
Is there a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree at least $2$ with rational (not all integer) coefficients such that $P(P(x))$ has integer coefficients?
Related to this MO question which uses assumptions about two compositions - it would be silly if there is no actual counterexample to what is asked here, but I cannot seem to find one.
Also, what if we impose the additional condition that $P(0)$ is an integer?
Any help appreciated!

An example without the $P(0)$ requirement is $P(x)=2x^2+\frac{1}{2}$

(Not a solution. Too long to be a comment. I pointed out that Srini's solution is in error, so here is my attempt at fixing it.)
Degree 2 case:
$$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \\
f(f(x)) =  a^3x^4 + 2a^2bx^3 + (2a^2c+ab^2+ab)x^2 + (2abc+b^2)x + (a^2 + bc + c ) $$

$c$ is an integer by assumption.

$a^3$ is an integer and $a$ is rational, so $a$ is an integer. So we can ignore any terms that involve only $a$ and $c$.

Let $ b = p/q$ in lowest terms.

From the $x$ term, since $b^2 + (2ac)b =k $ is an integer, so by rational root theorem, $q = 1$ thus $b$ is an integer.

(weaker result) From the $x^2$ term, $ab(b+1)$ is an integer, so $ q^2 \mid a$.


Degree 3 case:
$$ f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\
f(f(x)) = a^4 x^9 + 3 a^3 b x^8 + (3 a^3 c + 3 a^2 b^2) x^7 + (3 a^3 d + 6 a^2 b c + a^2 b + a b^3) x^6 + (6 a^2 b d + 3 a^2 c^2 + 3 a b^2 c + 2 a b^2) x^5 +   (6 a^2 c d + 3 a b^2 d + 3 a b c^2 + 2 a b c + b^3 ) x^4 + (3 a^2 d^2+6 a b c d + a c^3+ a c +  2 b^2 c) x^3   + (3 a b d^2 +3 a c^2 d + 2 b^2 d + b c^2+ b c) x^2 +  ( 3 a c d^2 + 2 b c d + c^2) x + (a d^3 + b d^2+ c d + d)$$
It's not clear to me if proceeding as the above would be that helpful.   Let's see what we can say ...

$d$ is an integer by assumption.

$a^4$ is an integer, so $a$ is an integer.

Let $b = p/q, c = m/n$, both in lowest terms.

From the $x^8$ term, $3a^3b$ is an integer, so $ q \mid 3a^3$.

From the $x$ term, multiply by $q$, $qc^2 + (3ad^2q+2bqd)c $ is an integer, so by rational root theorem, $n  \mid q $.

(weaker result) From the $x^7$ term, $(3a^3c  + 3a^2b^2)$ is an integer. Multiply that by $3a^4$ and subtracting $(3a^2b)^2$, we get that $9a^7 c$ is an integer. So $ n \mid 9a^7$.

From the $x^6$ term, $ab^3 +(a^2 + 6a^2c)b$ is an integer. Multiply that by $n$, and by rational root theorem, $q \mid an$. The chain of $ n \mid q \mid an$  could be interesting.

(Weaker result) From the $x^3$ term, $ac^3 + ac + 2b^2c + 6abcd$ is an integer. Multiply that by $q^2$, and by rational root theorem $n \mid aq^2$.

From the 1 term, $d(bd + c)$ is an integer.

(I don't see a nice way to complete this)



Calvin, Conrad, you both are right. I am deleting my wrong answer. Sorry couldn't find the right place to put that comment.

Not sure how useful it is, but we can prove that $15a^5 b^3$ is also an integer.
